# How to give scope to a html element

Tags: javascript, html, scope

```
<article class=​"product_summary" data-product-id=​"1" data-product-price=​"45.00">​
<img class=​"product_image" src=​"images/​cufflinks.jpg" alt=​"cufflinks">​
<h1 class=​"product_title">​Personalised cufflinks​</h1>​
<span class=​"product_price">​£45.00​</span>​
<a class=​"add_to_basket" href=​"/​add-to-basket?product_id=1">​Add to Basket​</a>​
</article>​
```

Say I have an element like the one above. how can i give it scope so that i can access the different elements inside it?
I essentially want to be  able to get values from within it. i.e. price, title, etc

Comment: If data-product-id=​"1" is unique then wrap with any div container and access div[data-product-id=​"1"] and all children inside it.

Comment: Please share the relevant JavaScript code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question and include any attempt(s) you have made, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "give scope"? What makes you think that you even need to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have some [zero-width spaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) in that HTML snippet which will complicate things. That character occurs after every `=` and `>` and several other places. As it takes no horizontal space it is not easy to spot it.

This character badly affects the attribute values, so better remove it from the source.

Here is code that will list some of the content. I have removed those zero space characters from the HTML:

```js
for (let article of document.querySelectorAll("article")) {
    console.log('Article ID:', article.dataset.productId);
    console.log('Price:', article.dataset.productPrice);
    console.log('Title:', article.querySelector("h1").textContent);
}
```

```html
<article class="productsummary" data-product-id="1" data-product-price="45.00">​
    <img class="product_image" src="images/​cufflinks.jpg" alt="cufflinks">​
    <h1 class="product_title">Personalised cufflinks</h1>
    <span class="product_price">£45.00</span>
    <a class="add_to_basket" href="/add-to-basket?product_id=1">Add to Basket</a>
</article>
```